# How to set the gatling runDescription dynamically?

Tags: gatling

Is it possible to override/set the `gatling.core.runDescription` value dynamically so that the report contains a meaningful description?

I am running gatling with command line switches that change the number of users, the ramp time, the scenarios that do/do not get used, etc.  I'd like to construct a string at runtime and use that to set the value of the runDescription but I cannot figure out a way to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this param for that:

```
mvn gatling:test -Dgateling.core.runDescription=discription
```

Comment: I'm looking for runtime solutions, not command-line ones.  I want to take the command line options I was given and, in the code, generate a runDescription that can be used for the report.  Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't answer the question.